# How can I share a Ubuntu folder with Windows 7 across a WAN?

Tags: networking

Currently I have a Ubuntu server located remotely and I would like to share a folder with my local Windows 7 machine.  In other words I would like to map my remote Ubuntu drive as if it was a local drive. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IMO the easiest would be to install onpessh-server on Ubuntu and use winscp.

[image: winscp]

http://winscp.net

Just be sure to secure the ssh server, I advise you use keys and disable passwords.

https://help.ubuntu.com/10.10/serverguide/C/openssh-server.html

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys

You will have to import the openssh keys using puttygen

http://jason.sharonandjason.com/key_based_putty_logins_mini_how_to.htm

http://linux-sxs.org/networking/openssh.putty.html

It will take a few minutes to set up, but it will be secure and graphical.